# GCP API Gateway + Identity Platform second tenant

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, openapi, multi-tenant, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have one question. I seted up a new tenant in my Identity Platform, and I need to set a security definition in a OpenAPI document for an API Gateway to authenticate users that ONLY belongs to this new tenant.

For example, for default firebase authentication would be something like this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/{projectID}"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "{projectID}"
```

And for authenticating a service account would be like this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  saOAuth:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "{saName}@{projectID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/{saName}@{projectID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "{someAudience}"
```

So, how can I make a definition for a specific tenant??

Comment: Do you have an issue when you try with a user from the 2nd tenant?

Comment: I haven't tested in deed with a user from a second tenant. But the real question is: how to allow ONLY the users from the default tenant and DENY access to the users from the second tenant

Comment: I think it's not possible. I didn't find an option for that